# validating a double input in java

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to validate a double input in java, but I keep getting error messages every time I change the method or the variable type. The code is as follows:

```
do{ 
      gpa = getDouble(" GPA:");
      gpaError = dblChecker(gpa);
       if(!gpaError){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try             Again!");//displays incorrect input message on JOptionPane
       }
      } while(!gpaError);// checks for proper input

public static String getInput(String data){
      String input = "";
      input = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your " + data);
      return input;
  }// end getInput information

private static String getString(String message) {
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message, "Input",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
return input;
}

private static double getDouble(String message) {
    String input = getInput(message);
    return Double.parseDouble(input);
    }   

 public static boolean dblChecker(String instr){
     boolean outBool = true;
     double tmpDbl = 0.0;
     try{
         tmpDbl = Double.parseDouble(instr);
         if(tmpDbl <= 0)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
     catch (Exception e){
         outBool = false;
     }
     return outBool;
 } //end validation for GPA
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: They want me to change my checking method to a double I/O a string. When I do that my parseDouble in the checker wants me to change it back to a string

Comment: This is a *whole lot* of code and only a tiny bit of it has to do with “validating a double input”.  You should start by defining (in English) you problem: What is a valid input?  Then, if you cannot implement it in Java, create a *minimal working example* with your current effort and explain why it does not do what you want.

Comment: The following dblChecker doesn't work. It wants me to change my checking method from a string to a double. That will be the 2nd code.

Comment: do{ 
    gpa = getDouble(" GPA:");
    gpaError = dblChecker(gpa);
     if(!gpaError){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Input. Please Try Again!");//displays incorrect input message on JOptionPane
     }
    } while gpaError);

Comment: public static boolean dblChecker(String instr){
   boolean outBool = true;
   double tmpDbl = 0.0;
   try{
    tmpDbl = Double.parseDouble(instr);
    if(tmpDbl <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   catch (Exception e){
    outBool = false;
   }
   return outBool;
  }

Comment: @Beth did you find your answer?

Comment: No I have not found one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Double.valueOf and it works

Answer (score 0):

### Save yourself some time and energy to focus on domain specific problems!

The native `.parse()` methods were written 20 years ago almost, they are a terrible API.

#### Use [Google Guava Doubles.tryParse();](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#tryParse(java.lang.String))

> Parses the specified string as a double-precision floating point
> value. The ASCII character '-' ('\u002D') is recognized as the minus
> sign. Unlike Double.parseDouble(String), this method returns null
> instead of throwing an exception if parsing fails. Valid inputs are
> exactly those accepted by Double.valueOf(String), except that leading
> and trailing whitespace is not permitted.
>
> This implementation is likely to be faster than Double.parseDouble if
> many failures are expected.

Comment: tryParse didn't work. I use Double.valueOf and it works.

Comment: @Beth:  I suspect that it would work if you include Guava on your classpath.